# More pythonic way of item_list[-1] != item_list[-2]?

Tags: python, list

I'm updating and then referring to the last item added to a list to determine an outcome, for example:

```
if item_list[-1] != item_list[-2]:
   outcome1
```

I don't need to refer to any other list element, just item_list[-1] & [-2].
Is there a more pythonic way of doing this? This code is for **on_message using **websockets****, and the item_list is being updated once per second or once per minute.
Any advice would be appreciated by this novice coder!

Comment: There's nothing unpythonic about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tricks like `*rest, x, y = item_list` and then compare, but I think your method is great.

Chasing a "more pythonic" method for something you already have a great method for, is sometimes unnecessary. I do however encourage and like your attempt at getting better. Keep it up!

And if your asking about efficiency - Your method is probably the best there is.

---

Per your pondering in the comments:

Just so you'll understand how fast it is, which is in the order of nanosecods and same speed no matter the length, here is a  benchmark:

```
> py -m timeit -s "a = list(range(10_000))" "a[-1]"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 73.3 nsec per loop

> py -m timeit -s "a = list(range(100_000))" "a[-1]"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 74.5 nsec per loop

> py -m timeit -s "a = list(range(1_000_000))" "a[-1]"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 69.6 nsec per loop
```

More than 10 billion lookups per second (on my old computer from 2009) is fast enough I think ;-)

Comment: Thanks very much, appreciate the feedback! The item list might be as much as 30,000 elements. My understanding is that this shouldn't impact speed/performance, is this correct?

Comment: Python calculates `-1` by taking the length (which is known) and accessing `(len-1)` in the fastest way possible. It's the same speed no matter the list length, and it's in the order of magnitude of nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are implemented as arrays, so getting at an index like that is a constant time operation. This means that there are no real inefficiencies in your code, and I don't see any readability concerns either. That said, if this check is the only thing you need the list for, you can probably simplify it to only store the last element and a boolean for whether that element matches the one before. However, to answer your specific question, there is no alternative way of writing it that is more pythonic.